# Assignments in Scala

Tags: scala

I've been shown a weird snippet in Scala which I don't quite understand. To me, assignments in Scala return `Unit`, unlike in Java where it returns the type of the variable which has been affected a value. However, let's consider this class :

```
case class C(i: Int) {
  def f = C(i = i + 10) 
}
```

This compiles completely fine, which is pretty weird ! The factory method `C.apply` expects an `Int`, whereas I pass it what seems to be an assignment, of type `Unit`. By the way if I remove the assignment to just let the expression, it seems to have the exact same behaviour.

Let's try this now :

```
case class C(i: Int) {
   def f = {
     i = i + 10
     C(i = i + 10)
   }
}
```

Ok now this is the world I know : `i` is a val, then you cannot mutate it so `i = i + 10` does not compile. However, `C(i = i + 10)` still compiles without complaining. What is this weirdness ? Is there a reason for thatto exist ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because, in the case of `C(i = i + 10)` the left-hand `i` is not the field `C#i` but a [named parameter](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/named-parameters.html).  No assignment is being done at all.

```
C(i = i + 10)
  ^   ^
  +---|-------- Parameter name
      |
      +- - - - - - - - - - - - - - Reference to the field `i`
                                   in the instance of the class `C`
```

Some places where named parameters make sense:

- Avoiding the "what does this `{boolean, integer}` mean" moment:

  ```
  someMethod(anObject, flagName=true)
  // As opposed to someMethod(anObject, true) ... what's `true` for? 

  anotherMethod(arg1, arg2, totalMagic=33)
  ```
- When using default values for parameters (to invoke the right constructor):

  ```
  def withDefaults(i: Int, flag: Boolean = true, wrapper: Option[String] = None) = {
    wrapper.fold(s"$i with $flag")(_.format(i, flag))
  }

  withDefaults(3, Some("stuff %s around %s"))
  // won't compile
  // error: type mismatch;
  //  found   : Some[String]
  //  required: Boolean

  withDefaults(3, wrapper = Some("stuff %s around %s"))
  // works (returns "stuff 3 around true")
  ```

Comment: Oh, right I did not know this syntax. Is there any advantage to do this ? I just tried using it and it allows, for example, to pass the parameters in a random order which I don't find really good as quite often the order of the parameters has some semantic

Comment: @Dici - updated with some examples of why you might use it